# Connecting a Symptom Object to and Identity Object in my Health App

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-class-based-views, modelform

I am creating a Health App that will take the Identity, Symptom, Disease and Treatment of the patient.

I have created models: Identity, Symptom, Disease, Treatment.
I am using `form.ModelForm` so that I can save the data to the db i.e. `sqlite3`.

I have created class based views that will handle forms, take field values, sanitize the data, and render the required form and values.

> **Problem**: Each time I attempt to save values for the Symptom form it
>   seems to save it, and redirect to a new form but I am not seeing it in
>   the Admin Backend.

**Code:**

**Model document**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Identity(models.Model):

    NIS =models.CharField(max_length = 200, primary_key = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, null = True )
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null = True)
    location  = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
    birthday= models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.first_name ,self.last_name)

class Symptom(models.Model):

    condition_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, default = '')
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 1000, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.condition_name

class Disease(models.Model):

    disease_name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, default = '')
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 1000, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.disease_name

class Treatment(models.Model):

    term = models.CharField(max_length = 80, default = '')
    treatment = models.TextField()
    patient = models.ManyToManyField(Identity, through = 'Consultation')
    date_done = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Term


class Consultation(models.Model):

    patient_identity = models.ForeignKey(Identity)
    patient_condition = models.ForeignKey(Symptom)
    patient_disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
    patient_treatment = models.ForeignKey(Treatment)
    date_seen = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.patient_identity)
```

**Views document**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView, DetailView, FormView, TemplateView
from patient.models import Identity, Symptom, Treatment, Disease, Consultation
from patient.forms import IdentityScript, SymptomScript


class Identity_view(CreateView):


    model = Identity

    template_name = 'patient/script.html'


    def get(self, request):

        form = IdentityScript()

        script = Identity.objects.all()

        var = {'form':form, 'script':script}

        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

    def post(self, request):

        form = IdentityScript(request.POST)


        being = None

        if form.is_valid():

            NIS = form.save(commit = False)

            NIS.user = request.user


            NIS.save()


            being = form.cleaned_data['first_name']


            form = IdentityScript()



            return redirect('script:script')

        var = {'form':form, 'being':being}

        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

class Identity_list_view(ListView):

    model = Identity

    template_name = 'patient/Identity_list.html'

    def get(self, request):

        form = IdentityScript()

        script = Identity.objects.all().order_by('-Timestamp')

        var = {'form':form, 'script':script}

        return render(request, self.template_name, var)




class Medical_document(CreateView):

    model = Symptom

    template_name = 'patient/medical_document.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):

        form = SymptomScript()

        expression = Symptom.objects.all()

        var = {'form':form, 'expression':expression, 'pk':pk}

        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

    def post(self, request, pk):

        form = SymptomScript()

        state = None

        if form.is_valid():

            manuscript = form.save(commit = False)
            manuscript.user = request.user
            state = form.cleaned_data['description']
            manuscript.save()

            patient = Identity.objects.get(pk=pk)

            form = SymptomScript()

            redirect('script:script')


        else:
            print(form)

        var = {'form': form, 'state':state, 'pk':pk}

        return render(request, self.template_name, var)
```

**Forms document**

```
from django import forms
from patient.models import Identity, Symptom, Disease

class IdentityScript(forms.ModelForm):

    NIS = forms.CharField(

        widget = forms.TextInput(

                attrs = {

                        'placeholder': 'Enter NIS',
                                'class' : 'form-control'
                }
        )
    )


    first_name = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(

                    attrs = {

                            'placeholder': 'Enter First Name',
                            'class' : 'form-control'
                    }
            )
    )



    last_name = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(

                    attrs = {

                              'placeholder': 'Enter Last Name',
                             'class' : 'form-control'
                    }
            )
    )

    contact = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(

                attrs = {

                        'placeholder':'Enter Contact',
                                'class':'form-control'
                }
        )
    )

    born = forms.DateField(

            widget = forms.TextInput(
                    attrs = {

                        'placeholder' : 'Enter Birth',
                            'class':'form-control'

                    }
            )
    )

    location = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(

                attrs = {

                        'placeholder':'Enter location',
                                'class':'form-control'
                }
        )
    )


    class Meta:

        model = Identity

        fields = ('NIS', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birthday', 'location', 'contact', )




class DiseaseScript(forms.ModelForm):

    disease_name = forms.CharField(

        widget = forms.TextInput(

                attrs = {

                        'placeholder': 'Enter Disease Name',
                                'class' : 'form-control'
                }
        )
    )

    description = forms.CharField(

        widget = forms.TextInput(

                attrs = {

                        'placeholder': 'Enter description',
                                'class' : 'form-control'
                }
        )
    )



    class Meta:

        model = Disease

        fields = ('disease_name', 'description')


# Create SymptomScript form

class SymptomScript(forms.ModelForm):

    condition_name = forms.CharField(

        widget = forms.TextInput(

                attrs = {

                        'placeholder': 'Enter Condition Name',
                                'class' : 'form-control'
                }
        )
    )

    description = forms.CharField(

        widget = forms.Textarea(

                attrs = {

                        'placeholder': 'Enter Description',
                                'class' : 'form-control'
                }
        )
    )

    class Meta:

        model = Symptom

        fields = ('condition_name', 'description')
```

Comment: Post your admin.py file(s), as this is what governs what appears on the admin backend

Comment: You are not passing `request.POST` to the `SymptomScript()` form when you initialise it in the `post` method - meaning it will never see any data.